Roots of linear combinations of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind and laplacian eigenvalues of the spider graph
Is there a closed formula for the roots of $\mathbf{U_L((x-2)/2)-(n-1) U_{L-1}((x-2)/2)}$?
Here $U_L(y)$ ($y=(x-2)/2$) are the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind and $n\geq 3$ is an integer.
Why am I asking?
I came across this question when looking at the eigenvalues of the 'combinatorial' Laplacian ($\Delta=D-A$) of 'spider graphs' (aka star-like trees), where a spider graph is a star graph just with longer legs.
Specifically, I am looking at symmetric spider graphs with $n$ legs of length $L$.
What I know
The solutions to the equation above provide $L$ eigenvalues with eigenvectors that are non-zero at the center (the spider's body).
One of these eigenvalues is larger than $4$ (for $n\geq 3$) and approaches $2 (n-1)+1/(n-1)$ for $L\to\infty$.
The other $(n-1)L$, non-trivial eigenvalues are given by those path-graph solutions (equation above for $n=2$), where the eigenvector is $0$ at the center and the eigenvalues can be expressed analytically (and degenerate with multiplicity $n-1$).
For many legs $n\to\infty$, the $U_L$ term can be ignored and the roots can be approximated by those of $U_{L-1}$.
BTW: Above results for the eigenvalues are largely known - see this paper and references https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7842; what is open is whether there is way to express the roots in closed form.
See also Dragan Stankow 'On linear combinations of chebyshev polynomials', e.g., http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/117/n111p057.pdf.
